# why am I getting 1 as result while extracting text from image using tesseract in python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been trying to extract text from images for my work using Tesseract, but whenever I run the code the answer I am getting is "1", no matter which image is applied and different codes.

```py
from pillow import Image
import tesseract
import pytesseract, re


#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

#Define path to image
path_to_image = 'images/sampletext1-ocr-539x450.png'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Open image with PIL
img = Image.open(path_to_image)

#Extract text from image
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text)
```

This is a code I copied from the web, tried several other codes and images with even single text on it
still, my answer is 1.

Comment: Probably `images/sampletext1-ocr-539x450.png` contains something that looks like a "1".

Comment: Could you provide an example picture, where you get 1?